not booting for ubuntu in legion 5 pro. Does not enter into ubuntu once dual booting
I tried to boot the lenovo legion 5 PRO, its getting to the dual boot option and once i opt for the ubuntu and hit ENTER, it again goes back to the dual boot status. The bios is in UEFI not LEGACY. I don't think we can change the bios now cause they stopped for lenovo laptops.

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? Some Lenovo have a "boot lock" setting in UEFI, so check various UEFI settings.
